# Event Report Template - Adding Sorting By/Group

Tags: civireport, joomla

How does one add "Organization" as a field to the sort list in the event report template?  I have found how to add custom fields but not system default fields.

Version 4.6.8 Joomla

Answer (score 1):

If you mean 'how do I show the Organisation that is the Employer of the person attending the event' then you need to see if the 'Current Employer' field is available for that event.
"Organisation" is not a field per se. It is a Contact Type.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am new to CiviCRM so please bare with me

I have looked in Event Templates then looked into the profiles on those templates. Some of the profiles have Current Employer, but not all. Also, none of the Current Employer fields are searchable.

1.) Am I looking in the right spot?  (Event Templates -> Template -> Online Registration -> Include Profile)
2.) Is there a place to modify "Current Employer" system-wide?

Also, when I am editing the profile and I change a field like Individual:Current Employer to Searchable it doesn't keep the settings after I hit save.

Comment: Not sure if you are clear on the differences between Fields and Profiles. Fields ie Core and Custom Fields are in the db, the profiles then 'use' those fields (poor description but hope that helps, otherwise familiarise y'self with the Manual some more). So when you say you edit the Current Employer field in teh Profile, I would expect that to only change it in that profile, not systemically. Also Current Employer will only be in some Profiles because you make the choice on what is in the Profile. BUT your original post referred to 'reports' so there is risk of confusion around terminology.

Comment: it may help if you set something up in demo and then link to that so we can be sure we are talking about the same concepts ;-) (and welcome to civi)

Comment: Thanks for that and your patience with me! Yes. My goal is just to get the "current employer" as a column that can be sorted and grouped by in the Event Participant Report.  In that report it seems "current employer" is named "organization."  Organization in the report is a valid column to view, but not to sort or group by.  I need to group by.   Does that simplify it?  If not, I will try create a demo site as you suggested.

Comment: Hi again. Sorry it looks like i really didn't get the original question on a quick skim.  A url helps so much. Are talking about http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/report/instance/25?reset=1  (drupal demo but same for joomla)? And if so you are saying "Organisation Name" field is available on the Columns Tab (may translate differently if site not in English) but is not currently available on the Sorting tab? If so, it may help to edit the Question to help others help you (since I don't seem to be doing such a good job)

Comment: I figured it out! It was just a PHP file that needed some arrays tweaked. /administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Report/Form/Event/ParticipantListing.php.  I find it interesting that these "settings" are hardcoded into the PHP files.  Thanks again!