# CiviReport Participant Sort by Event Start Date

Tags: civireport, joomla

I am trying to create a report that lists the participants for upcoming events (each day for the next 14 days), sorted by event start date as the section header. Event Start Date is not listed in the Column dropdown.

Event Start Date 
-Event type
--Participant Name 1
--Participant Name 2

Next Day Start Date
-Event type
--Participant Name 1
--Participant Name 3

I saw [this](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/6897/event-report-template-adding-sorting-by-group) thread that gives me hope, but it doesn't specifically say how it was fixed. I've scoured the web trying to find a solution, but have come up with nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, it's pretty silly that event start date isn't available as a header.  It's actually a really small change in the code, but it does require editing the code to add the field as an sorting option.

I made a change that will hopefully be included in the next 4.6 release, but you can add it by editing the appropriate file.  In your CiviCRM codebase (found at sites/all/modules/civicrm in Drupal, administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm in Joomla, or wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm in WordPress), edit the file at `CRM/Report/Form/Event/ParticipantListing.php` to apply the changes you see here: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/7221/files after line 299.

Comment: Fantastic! I was fumbling with the other explanation; so close but just couldn't make it work. This is exactly what I need. Thank you.