# CiviReport sort event list by start date

Tags: civireport

Similar to [CiviReport Participant Sort by Event Start Date](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7684/civireport-participant-sort-by-event-start-date)

I would like my event report (Extended Report - Statistics across events) to display events ordered by event start date.

I am on CiviCRM 5.13.4 with Wordpress.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: Which report are looking to sort event by start date?

Comment: Extended Report - Statistics across events: a list of events with title, start and end date.

Comment: You will need to alter the report using hook to add sortings.

Comment: And where do I find some documentation on that?